# Configuring smart monitoring tools in Zabbix Agent and Server 4

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, health-monitoring

I am trying to use this to monitor hdd health:
https://share.zabbix.com/storage-devices/smartmontools/smart-monitoring-with-smartmontools-lld

I have followed the steps for the agent and server (at least that is my understanding) and would like to know how can I check the monitoring status. even though I might only get an alert in the dashboard if something goes wrong, I would like to see the current status, understand if monitoring is working and everything is ok.

I have followed the linux agent installation steps here: https://github.com/v-zhuravlev/zbx-smartctl

I have also imported the template on the zabbix frontend, and associated the template with the server being monitored.

What now? How can I check if this is working? It seems like there is something missing, but I am not sure where or how to check.

*UPDATE:*

I am using this template (which mentions Zabbix 3.4) even though I am using Zabbix 4. Since the template in Zabbix Share mentioned it was compatible with 3.4+, I assume this is not an issue: https://github.com/v-zhuravlev/zbx-smartctl/blob/master/Template_3.4_HDD_SMARTMONTOOLS_2_WITH_LLD.xml

Answer (score 0):

Now you should go to "Latest data" and select your server as a host.
You will get the list of the discovered items where you will find the items related to the disk health.
Then, try to select an item and build with it a graph for example and put it in a dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for you  reply but that does not seem to work. I had already tried that, and I see no data. Here is an example: https://snipboard.io/OC9Fab.jpg